# How can I fetch the value from the given string using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

With the following string value: - `Comet TV Hd (599|C07)`

I'm trying to get only - `Comet TV Hd`

I tried - `(\w+\s*\w+)\s`

It is working fine for 2 words, it fetches Comet TV and I can further modify it to work for 3 words as following - `(\w+\s*\w+\s*\w+)\s`

But I want a solution which isn't dependent on the number of words. How can I change this expression such that it captures any number of words prior to, from the example, `(599|C07)`

Comment: Try this: `^([\w\s]+)\s+\(`. `^` matches the start of the string. `([\w\s]+)` matches one or more word characters or whitespace characters and captures them in a group. `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters. `\(` matches an open parenthesis.

Comment: It's not clear what the format is, exactly.  Is your question "how can I capture every before the first parenthesis?"  Or perhaps before the _last_ open parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex pattern to match any number of words before the specific pattern, such as `(599|C07)`:

`^(.+?)\s+\(.*`

Here's a breakdown of the regex pattern:

1. `^` The start of the line.
2. `(.+?)` Capture any number of characters (non-greedy) in a group. The non-greedy `+?` quantifier ensures that the group captures the least amount of characters possible, stopping at the first occurrence of the subsequent pattern.
3. `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters.
4. `\(.*` Match the literal parentheses, and anything after it. `\(` is escaped to match the literal parentheses, `.` matches any character except newlines, and the quantifier `*` makes it match zero or more characters.

This regex pattern will capture any number of words prior to a pattern like (599|C07) regardless of the number of words.

[You can experiment with it here.](https://regexr.com/7bvfl)

Comment: Depending on what can be in the pattern in your fourth step, this may be underinclusive.

Comment: True. I updated regex to ignore anything after the initial parenthesis.